# Php, MySql threaded comments limit

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to limit number of records based on parent/child relationship;

I have a simple comments table:

```
id      parent_id
==============
1       0     
2       1
3       1
4       0
5       4
6       4
```

and my query:

```
  SELECT 
    id,
    parent_id
  FROM
    comments 
  ORDER BY parent_id LIMIT 0,5;
```

The problem is, since comments are nested, it will cut of in a middle of child comment. What I  would like is, to select x number of items, but to include children as well.

Comment: What about grandchildren?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kid.*
FROM 0_a AS kid
JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM 0_a WHERE root_id = 0 LIMIT 5
) AS p ON kid.id = p.id OR kid.root_id = p.id
ORDER BY kid.id
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your query partial works, For example if I want to sort by date column, it ignores it completely "ORDER BY kid.created"